# how to loop through workbooks in a folder and unmerge cells and fill them up

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Basically I am trying to check the workbooks in a folder (around 12 workbooks), some sheets in these workbooks have merged cells which I would like to unmerge and fill them with the top most value. Following is what I have tried.

If I use the code below for a single workbook, it works.

```
Sub Findmergedcellsandfill()


    Dim MergedCell As Range,
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    Dim MergeAddress As String
    Dim MergeValue As Variant

    Application.FindFormat.MergeCells = True

      Do

        Set MergedCell = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchFormat:=True)
        If MergedCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        MergeValue = MergedCell.Value
        MergeAddress = MergedCell.MergeArea.Address
        MergedCell.MergeArea.UnMerge
        Range(MergeAddress).Value = MergeValue
      Loop
      Application.FindFormat.Clear

End Sub
```

to check all workbooks and do this code, I tried the below method, but doesnt really do anything, appreciate if someone could help me with it.

```
Sub findandfilltheunmergedcells()

    Dim FolderPath As String    
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim MergedCell As Range, FirstAddress As String, MergeAddress As String, MergeValue As Variant


    FolderPath = "C:\Users\docs\"


    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xl*")


    Do While FileName <> ""

        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)

        Application.FindFormat.MergeCells = True


    Do

        Set MergedCell = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find("", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchFormat:=True)
            If MergedCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            MergeValue = MergedCell.Value
            MergeAddress = MergedCell.MergeArea.Address
            MergedCell.MergeArea.UnMerge
            Range(MergeAddress).Value = MergeValue
    Loop

        Application.FindFormat.Clear

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Missing `FileName = Dir()` just before your second `Loop`

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing this bit. The program runs now as expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you merge a group of cells only top most value is retained.

Open all the Workbooks that you would like to process.  Then run UnMergeCellsOfAllOpenWorkbooks()

```
Sub UnMergeCellsOfAllOpenWorkbooks()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.Cells.MergeCells = False
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for an alternative code solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through all files in a folder, open each, make the change, in this case un-merge cells, then save the change and close the files, one by one.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ErrorYes As Boolean

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then


                'Change cell value(s) in one worksheet in mybook
                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    sh.Cells.MergeCells = False
                End With


                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrorYes = True
                    Err.Clear
                    'Close mybook without saving
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                Else
                    'Save and close mybook
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=True
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                'Not possible to open the workbook
                ErrorYes = True
            End If

        Next Fnum
    End If

    If ErrorYes = True Then
        MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
             & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```